# What happens when some users ask their friends to increase their reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation

What happens if some of the users ask their friends to create accounts on stackoverflow and upvote all of their questions and answers and gain lots of reputation ? That is not allowed right ?

Comment: does it matter? Rep is overrated anyways, it's not like it's money.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the votes are excessive, the voting abuse scripts will be activated and the votes along with associated reputation will be reversed.  If it is just a few, then they will go unnoticed for the most part.

You could do it, but if you dig deep down, I think you will know the correct action and if this is right or wrong.

The ♦'s are always watching though and will take action if we notice anything.

Comment: *The ♦'s are always watching...*

Comment: @mmyers♦: Shouldn't it be "Big ♦ is watching you"?

Answer (score 3):

This type of activity will be automatically detected by the vote-fraud detection scripts. The votes will be cancelled and the user's reputation recalculated. In addition, the Stack Overflow Team might take additional action, such as suspension or banning, where appropriate.

Comment: Only if you get a single person to upvote you a lot, if you get everyone at work to upvote a single quesion of yours that the team needs the answer to, then the vote-fraud detection scripts will not kick in.

Answer (score 2):

Their accounts get deleted and they can never ever come back!

No, seriously, all those votes are rollbacked once a day when the anti-fraud script detects it -- no one got passed that for it to be such a problem to warrant a ban I think (yet).

Answer (score 2):

Then the super-duper algorithms that power the system eventually spot that it's happened and cancel out all of the up-votes.

It's really not worth it and above all, it's a little bit silly, really.